# What is the "Bitcoin Address" for standard multisig transaction?

Tags: multi-signature

## Question

A standard multisig transaction is:

- scriptPubkey = `m <p1> ... <pn> n OP_CHECKMULTISIG`
- scriptSig = `OP_0 <s1> ... <sm>`

Where: 1 <= m <= n <= 3.

Note, that it is not P2SH transaction!

So, what is the Bitcoin Address for this transaction?
In case of escrow, what Bitcoin Address should be provided to the trading parties?

## Short glossary

p = public key

pH = public key hash, RIPEMD(SHA(public key))

sH = hash of serialized script, RIPEMD(SHA(ser. script))

C = first 4-bytes of SHA256(SHA256(data), where data is

X = bitcoin address prefix (0x00 for P2PKH transaction, 0x05 for P2SH transaction)

0pHC = concatenation of bytes (0: 1-byte, pH: 32-bytes, C: 4-bytes)

## Bitcoin Addresses

#### P2PK transaction

The "Bitcoin Address" for P2PK is **Base58(XpC)**, where "X" (bitcoin address prefix) is not currently defined for P2PK transaction type. See https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes.

Where:

- **X** is the bitcoin address prefix (for example, 0x02)
- **p** is the public key
- **C** is the checksum (SHA^2(public key))
- **XpC** is the concatenation of **X** byte, **p** string and **C** 4-bytes

#### P2PKH transaction

The "Bitcoin Address" for P2PKH transaction is **Base58(0pHC)**.

#### P2SH transaction

The "Bitcoin Address" for P2SH transaction is **Base58(5sHC)**.

So, again, what may be the Bitcoin Address for standard multisig transaction?

Thanks,
--- Kosta Z.

Answer (score 2):

A standard multisig transaction does not have a bitcoin address. This is precisely why it is wrapped as the redeem script of a P2SH bitcoin address.

Raw multisig transactions are not used anymore.

Comment: Can you please point to the BIP or the source code that disables the use of the raw multisig? Thanks!